# In Layer navigation side bar how to display the all category

Tags: magento2

I have three main categories and for each, I have 2 subcategories. I want to display all the category in layered navigation.

Comment: How many level you have? I mean depth.

Comment: Hi Thank you for comment. I have 3 levels.